# Only adding score to bot team

Tags: python

I'm brand new to coding in python, was just messing around and I was wondering why my code was only adding the score to the bot and not me. I know this is asking for a lot but please explain why it doesn't work

```
 from random import *
 import random
 from random import randrange
 HumanPoints = 0
 botPoints = 0
 while True: 
 print('Im thinking of a number between one and two')
 print('first to 5 points wins')
 randomNum = randint(1, 2)
 answer = input() 
 if answer == randomNum:
    HumanPoints = HumanPoints + 1 
    print('You have {} points'.format(HumanPoints))
    print('I have {} points'.format(botPoints))
 if answer != randomNum:
    botPoints = botPoints + 1 
    print('You have {} points'.format(HumanPoints))
    print('I have {} points'.format(botPoints))
 if HumanPoints >= 1:
    break
 if botPoints >= 1:
    break
 while True:
 print('ok choose 1 or 2')
 randomNum = randint(1, 2)
 answer = input() 
 if answer == randomNum:
    HumanPoints = HumanPoints + 1 
    print('You have {} points'.format(HumanPoints))
    print('I have {} points'.format(botPoints))

 if answer != randomNum:
    botPoints = botPoints + 1 
    print('You have {} points'.format(HumanPoints))
    print('I have {} points'.format(botPoints))
 if HumanPoints >= 5:
    print('you win')
    break
 if botPoints >= 5:
   print('you lose')
   break
```

Comment: Please give a more specific [mcve]. In the process, note that one space really isn't enough indentation for readable code; [the official style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends four.

Comment: I think this question is a little too close to a code-dump + "help me". SO expects some description of what steps you've taken to debug. 

If you haven't taken _any_ steps to debug, you would probably benefit from reviewing a few Python tutorials rather than posting as soon as you hit a snag.

I suggest you read up on breakpoints and how to trace through the execution of your script to inspect variable values.

Answer (score 0):

`input()` gives you the user input as a string, not as an number. If the user types 1, then `answer` will be `"1"`, not `1`.

The user never gets points because `"1" != 1` and `"2" != 2`.

Change `answer = input()` to `answer = int(input())`.

Answer (score 0):

Input is a string ("1" or "2"). A string can never equal a number. Try this:

```
answer = int(input())
```

This will make answer equal to the integer the player types.